# rsync from Solaris to Windows (character encoding on filenames)

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, rsync, solaris

I'm trying to use RSYNC to sync files from a Solaris 9 (SunOS 5.9) System to a Windows Server 2008 R2 (via cygwin)

There are many Files containing characters like "ä", "ö", "ü" or "ß". Which are only shown correctly when Windows-Users access the Solaris-Samba-Share.
Rsync shows those characters as: #201 for "ü"
After copying to windows the characters become "dots" like these:

- <-- Dot

And  on solaris they look like this: ▒

Is it possible to use rsync's "--iconv"-functionality to convert the filenames into the correct format?
How do I determine the filename-encoding on the solaris machine?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and found, that you can use the tool [convmv](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/) to find the encoding for the file and then use rsync's `--iconv` option.

1. Download convmv from https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/ and extract
2. Check the available encodings with `convmv --list`
3. Try (or write a script) which encoding works with convmv e.g. with `convmv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8 /path/to/file` (the return code in `$?` is 0 when the conversion worked and not 0 otherwise)
4. When the right encding is found, use rsync with the `--iconv` parameter, e.g. `rsync --iconv=ISO-8859-1,UTF-8 /source /destination`